# Firebase database rules for a collection shared with two users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have this collection

```
"connection-requests":{
    "push-key1":{
        "foo":"bar",
        "biz":"baz",
        "user1":{
            "some-info":"",
            "uid":"user1uid"
        },
        "user2":{
            "some-info":"",
            "uid":"user2uid"
        }
    }
}
```

I want this collection to be readable and writable only by the two users whose `uid` is present this collection.

This is my database rules:

```
"connection-requests": {
    "$key": {
        ".read": "root.child('connection-requests').child($key).child('user1/uid').val() == auth.uid || root.child('connection-requests').child($key).child('user2/uid').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "root.child('connection-requests').child($key).child('user1/uid').val() == auth.uid || root.child('connection-requests').child($key).child('user2/uid').val() == auth.uid",
    }
}
```

Im accessing the data using this request :

```
db.ref('connection-requests')
    .orderByChild('user1/uid')
    .equalTo(uid) // <- auth.uid of user
    .once('value')
    .then()
    .catch()
```

The rules above doesn't work, my guess is that there is something wrong with `.child($any)` part but Im not sure what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The closing double-quote for each rule is misplaced.  Instead of being at the end of the line, it is following the OR operator:

```
auth.uid || "root.child
            ^
            ^
```

Should be:

```
"connection-requests": {
    "$key": {
        ".read": "root.child('connection-requests') ... == auth.uid",
        ".write": "root.child('connection-requests') ... == auth.uid",
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Bob, thanks for pointing that mistake, but it was just a typo upon making the question.